# Python: How do add leading zeros to a binary? When I try it adds them to the left of the 0b

Tags: python

In this example...

```
temp = 0b110
print temp
temp.str(temp).zfill(8)
print temp
```

the output is...

```
0b110
0000b110
```

How do I add the zeros so I see an eight bit binary output, 0b00000110?

Comment: That can't be your code. `temp.str` is going to be an `AttributeError`. Please give us a [mcve].

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yeah, I realized that in editing the comment to fix that it was also going to take more explanation, so I canceled, created an answer, and then it was too late to edit the comment, so I deleted it.

Comment: It was a good question, but I don't understand why the asker gave false code.  If anyone wants an answer to their question, it seems like they'd provide a plausible example.  Even the `print temp` doesn't print a binary number, it prints `6`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're calling the `bin` function, or using a format string with `#b`, or whatever, the resulting string has `0b` on the front, so it's too late to zero-fill, unless you want to do something hacky like pull it off, zero-fill to n-2 characters, then put it back on.

But if you just do the zero-filling before (or while) adding the prefix rather than after, it's easy. For example:

```
>>> temp = 0b110
>>> format(temp, '#010b')
'0b00000110'
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) explain this in detail, but the short version is:

- `#` means "alternate form", which gives me the `0b` prefix
- `0` means zero-pad
- `10` means width of 10 (including the `0b`)
- `b` means binary